# Swift: Connecting to multiple peers using Multipeer Connectivity

Tags: ios, swift, multipeer-connectivity

Say I have 3 peers: A, B and C. If peers A and B are connected, when C connects to B, does that mean that C is also implicitly connected with A?

I'm working on an iOS app that involves creating a local chat room. 
A user can either create and start advertising a new chat room, or they browse for and join an existing one. However, when they want to join the room, I'm having trouble figuring out whether or not they need to connect to just one person who is advertising the chat room, or all of the people that are already in and advertising the chat room. (once a person joins a chat room they automatically start advertising it to others which means that every user in a chat room is advertising the session)

I'm aware of Apple's sample group chat project but unfortunately it is in objective-C and didn't seem to be of much help to me. Their project is set up so that users have to be invited to a chat room whereas I would like users to be able to request to join a chat room and not have to be explicitly invited.

I was going to make a test app to try and figure out some of these answers but I figured it was at least worth asking first. Any help is appreciated!